# "Target (y) not found or it is not numeric" -Package smbinning - R

Tags: discretization

I am trying to use smbinning package in R software to find optimal binnings to a certain variable. Running the command

```
result=smbinning(df=bop,y="FLAG_TARGET",x="VL_TOTL_REND",p=0.05)
```

returns the following error message:

> "Target (y) not found or it is not numeric"

What is happening here? `FLAG_TARGET` is numeric and I have already tried to change data format to integer but it does not work.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: That happened to me too -  A tibble doesn't equal a data frame for this package to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `bop` is not a data frame, you have to convert bop into data frame with `as.data.frame(bop)`. If you look at the full smbinning code (https://github.com/cran/smbinning/blob/master/R/smbinning.R#L490), there is this block

```
i=which(names(df)==y) # Find Column for dependant
j=which(names(df)==x) # Find Column for independant
if (!is.numeric(df[,i]))
{ 
    return("Target (y) not found or it is not numeric")
}
```

after setting y as the target column name and x as the predictor column name, try running

```
i = which(names(bop) == y)
j = which(names(bop) == x)
is.numeric(bop[,i])
```

if bop is not a dataframe, it will return `FALSE`. After running `bop_dataframe <- as.data.frame(bop)` and running

```
is.numeric(bop_dataframe[,i])
```

it should return `TRUE`